# Evaluating partial derivative of a double summation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Suppose I am given a function $f(x_i,y_j) = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m y_j\log(x_i)$.

I want to evaluate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$. Am I correct in assuming that

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^m y_j}{x_i}$, as the partial derivative of all $x_{i'}, i' \neq i$ equals 0, so the summation drops out?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Thank you! If $f(x_i,y_j)$ = $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m y_j x_i$ and I wanted to evaluate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$, is it then simply $\sum_{j=1}^m y_j$ instead of $\sum_{j=1}^m y_j n$ right?

Comment: Yes, as writing out the terms explicitly, the only terms with $x_i$ in them are $x_iy_1+\ldots+x_iy_n$.

Comment: Thanks you! That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Just to visualize the problem (I think it can be  useful) consider that your double sum is the sum of the elements of the following matrix

$$  \left[ \begin{matrix}
    y_1\log x_1& y_1\log x_2 & \dots & y_1\log x_n \\
    y_2\log x_1& y_2\log x_2 & \dots & y_2\log x_n \\
    \dots & \dots  & \dots &\dots  \\
    y_m\log x_1 & y_m\log x_2 & \dots & y_m\log x_n \\
    \end{matrix}\right]$$

thus derivating w.r.t. $x_i$ the result is the sum of the elements of the following matrix

$$  \left[ \begin{matrix}
    y_1/x_1& y_1/x_2 & \dots & y_1/x_n \\
    y_2/x_1& y_2/x_2 & \dots & y_2/ x_n \\
    \dots & \dots  & \dots &\dots  \\
    y_m/x_1 & y_m/ x_2 & \dots & y_m/x_n \\
    \end{matrix}\right]$$

That is

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=\frac{1}{x_i}\Sigma_{j=1}^m y_j$$

$i=1,2,\dots,n$

Comment: Thank you! That is very instructive.

Comment: @Golem :  you're welcome. Do not forget to upvote and accept my answer!